# Treat "-" (hyphen) as a letter for word-wrap

Tags: html, css

I want to treat the "-" Symbol as just another letter for the word-wrap property. Is there any way to do this?

For example:
If I have a legend with word-wrap: normal, with a width to accomodate 3 letter words it will insert a line break into ttt-hhh but it won't do that for tttfhhh. I want ttt-hhh to behave the same way as tttfhhh does, without changing the width of the legend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to accomplish this with CSS.

Anyway, it is possible to use a [nonbreaking hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen#Nonbreaking_hyphens) (`‑`) instead of the minus sign.

The nonbreaking hyphen can be written as `&#8209;` in HTML where Unicode is not available.